# Neo4j Node security access controls

Tags: neo4j

I'm looking to have node access controls by implementing custom properties on the nodes themselves and having trouble determining the best path to take.  Access to these need to be determined on the fly and cannot be determined beforehand.

For example:

Let's say I have

```
(bob:Person {name: "Bob",access:"1000000000}) - [:KNOWS] -
  (adam:Person {name:"Adam",access:"110010000"})
```

Based on the access object, there can be up to 512 different combinations to determine access to an object. In reality, the access level can have even more variations and may expand in the future.  Ideally, what I would be able to do is to filter out the nodes/relationships for any query that is run against this DB.  I started looking into custom procedures but I'm unsure if that's the best approach.

Comment: How exactly are the `access` properties supposed to be used?

Comment: They're intended to control access to information based on a particular user's permissions.  Conceptually, each user has a very specific subgraph they can access and run queries against.

Comment: So, a user has a specific `access` string, and s/he can only access nodes/relationships with the same `access` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every DB user has a specific `access` string, and s/he can only access nodes/relationships with the same `access` value, then it is very easy to filter for that.

For example, to get all user-visible paths (assuming that the user's `access` value is passed in via the `$access` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/syntax/parameters/)):

```
MATCH p=(a:Person)-[k:KNOWS]->(b:Person)
WHERE
  a.access = $access AND
  k.access = $access AND
  b.access = $access
RETURN p;
```

Or, more generically (but perhaps less efficiently):

```
MATCH p= <an arbitrary path expression>
WHERE
  ALL(n IN NODES(p) WHERE n.access = $access) AND
  ALL(r IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) WHERE r.access = $access)
RETURN p;
```

Comment: Sorry, should have delved more into how the access model works.

Each pair of numbers represent access perms for a particular type of data and having a positive value gives you access to lower levels.
00 - no access
01 - access to lvl 1
10 - access to lvl 1,2
Outside of the tuples, the overall combination may also impose its own access permissions.  It's a complex mechanism which needs to be calculated on a per node basis.  I can get a y/n by calling a function that takes user with node permissions.  So I'd need to filter the graph based on calling this against every node.

Comment: Re: "per node basis" --> do you mean "per node AND per relationship"? Also, if you are looking for a Cypher approach, it *might* be possible to do it in our Cypher (depending on the business logic), or you could write your own [procedure or function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/extending-neo4j/procedures/).

Comment: I amended my original question/title.  I realized this access model only applies to the node itself, not the relationship.  Based on our back and forth, I'm thinking a custom function might fit the bill better.  Your help is much appreciated!